# How to check SMS delivery date in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sms

I'm trying to implement the following requirement in Salesforce Marketing Cloud:

> (10-15 SMS/month) before getting another SMS text.

**Approach**:  I run a query on the _UndeliverableSms data view, but that helps me to only know if the sms was undelivered or not. Potentially, i want to get a Data Extension with list of users that has not received SMS in last 3 days and use automation studio.

**Problem**: How can i get the delivery date timestamp, if the message is delivered?

Answer (score 0):

I have found an article which you might find helpful:

https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/mobile_messages/tracking_mobile_messages/

Thanks!